# Qt: hiding border for selected tab in QTabBar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, tabs, qtabbar

QTabBar has a 1px border that separates tabs from their content.

```
QTabWidget::pane { border:1px solid #C4C4C3; }
```

I want the border to disappear under selected tab, like it's done in all browsers and most of applications using tabs.

However, setting styles for QTabBar::tab doesn't help:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected { border-bottom-color:white; }
```

[image]

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That line is controlled by the top border of `QTabWidget::pane`. 
For example:

```
QTabWidget::pane { border: 1px solid #C4C4C3; top: -1px; }
```

would move the line behind/under the tabs (somehow using `top` alone seems to remove the border completely).

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed. Didn't think about that `top:-1px`.